# How Well Are the Following Metrics For My RNN?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am somewhat new to the concept of the metrics MAE and RMSE, I know that using these metrics instead of accuracy is reccomended since I use regression instead of classification. I am wondering how to measure the true accuracy of my model, the labeled sets are either -1 or 1 depending on the specified inputs, and my model outputs both negative and positive numbers linearly. Here are the following graphs that were returned on training:
[image]

My model doesn't appear to look overfitted in comparison to both training and testing lines, also what does it signify that RMSE is .5 and cannot go any lower? Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mean squared error calculates the squared difference between the predicted labels and the true labels.

[image]

On the other hand, Root mean squared error calculates the squared difference between the predicted labels and the true labels just like MSE, but unlike MSE, it then takes the square root of it. Therefore, RMSE calculates the absolute distance between the predicted labels and the true labels.
[image]

For example, if your model predicts 1 but the true label is -1, then,

MSE = {1-(-1)}^2 = 4

RMSE = √MSE = √4 = 2